# How do I solve the following scenario : adding images when pushing button?

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style, qt5

I have the following problem to solve. I am working on my programm for my Bachelorthesis and I have to create a Qt program, which adds a picture if I push add, right next to the old picture. I explain you by showing pictures.

[image: Before clicked add]

So if I click on my add button this should happen:

[image: 2nd]

And so on.
At the moment, I just hide labels and make them visible if you push add. I guess it's not the best way to solve it. I was thinking about an array of labels or something like that.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: add a QLabel containing your image in QHBoxLayout

Comment: a bit more specific plz. actually i cant find that box

Comment: you have a widget that will contain all your QLabels (images). In this widget you set a QHBoxLayout, which initially would be empty (no images). Every time you push the button, you load your image, put it in a QLabel, and add the QLabel to the layout with layout->addWidget(...), so that the new image will appear to the right of the last one.

Comment: ok i understand. like dynamic labels right? u have the time to give me a short code snippet? so i can make it fit for my programm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83493/discussion-between-frederik-ubben-and-miki).